# Multiplicative version of "summation"

Tags: summation, products

Repeated sum is denoted using $\sum$ and is called "summation."  What is the name for the analogous process with multiplication, denoted $\prod$?

Comment: "summation" is the action of adding and getting a sum.  So I imagine the equivalent word for the action of multiplying and getting a product would be .... "production".  But If never heard anyone every use it.  We refer to $\Sigma$ as "summation notation" and an actual result as a "sum" and we refer to $\Pi$ as "product notation" and an actual result as a "product".  So maybe "product" is the word.  Then,  what exactly do you mean and when do you use the word "summation".  Maybe the word should be "multiplication". Anywho... math aint always english so .....

Comment: Yeah it's just to be concise in method-naming on my application because product to me sounds like the individual product of two values, not $n$ values. But it's probably just the way it has been taught to me in the past. I suppose you can indeed think of the "product" to be the multiplication of $n$ factors as well.

Comment: "summation" refers to a process of adding many items - and I don't know of a word for the multiplicative analogue of that. However, $\sum \ldots$ is not a summation, it's a **sum**. And $\prod \ldots$ is a **product**.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols#Linear_and_multilinear_algebra) it's simply **product**

Comment: "because product to me sounds like the individual product of two values, not n values."  Ah,, well, I *can* tell you that a product most certainly be a product of multiple even infinite numbers. There's no problem *there*.  And the more I think of it "summation" isn't actually a mathematical word at all; it's just an adjective *about* sums.

Comment: "According to wikipedia it's simply product" But *also* according to the same article $\Sigma$ refers to a "sum"; not a "summation". Actually that article talked of what the *meant*; not what they are called.  I have heard $\Sigma$ referred to as the "summation symbol" (and $\Pi$ as the "product symbol") but I don't think in actual mathematics I don't think the word "summation" is used all that frequently or meaningfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are finitely many terms to be multiplied, it is just called a product.

If $S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n A_j$ and if $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} S(n)$ exists then we say $L=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j.$

Similarly if $P(n)=\prod_{j=1}^n B_j$ and if $M=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n)$ exists then we write $M=\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j.$ And we call $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j$ an infinite product.

There might be differing terminology in other languages. Jargon is not always translated verbatim.